# Port 22 network error on git batch when trying to commit files

Tags: java, spring, git, gitlab, git-bash

I was added to GitLab and I created my repository , now I am trying to clone the repository and commit files to the repo but I keep getting ssh network error port 22 . I have added my ssh key with the email address that was used to add me to the GitLab account but i still can't commit . What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possible reasons for this. Perhaps you are on a network which blocks traffic to port 22. Trying your connection from another network or device would be the best way to quickly test for this.

If that is the case you can change the port (make sure it is an available one) that your ssh service listens on in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` and change to the same here: `config/gitlab.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks , how do I locate the sshd_conf file ? I have searched registr editor but I can't seem to find it

Comment: You tagged the question with git-bash, so I assume you are using the git terminal. You can open the file using your favorite editor, for example like so: `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_conf`